# How to import packages in nested directories (Haxe)?

Tags: haxe

I've a main Haxe script in a file called Main.hx. And in this same script I can import any existent package, including other Haxe scripts in the same directory that are considered package, but Haxe scripts (which should be considered package) that are declared in nested directories doesn't work with `import` (I'm almost sure that they're being ignored).

Haxe is just sayin' that `Test` doesn't exist. When I try to get `wow.test.Test` it says the same thing, and same with `test.Test`. I've also tried to set the package name at `./wow/test.hx` as `wow.test` and `test`, and it was the same situation.

It only works if I throw `test.hx` outside of `./wow` and import its things normally, like: `test.*` instead of `wow.test.*`.

---

My test structure:

—— ./Main.hx ——

```
package;

import haxe.unit.TestCase;
import openfl.display.Sprite;
import native.*;
import wow.test.*;

class Main extends Sprite
{

    public function new ()
    {
        super ();
        new Test();
    }
}
```

—— ./wow/test.hx ——

```
package;

class Test
{
    public function new ()
    {
        trace("Dum !!");
    }
}
```

---

Or would I need to configure that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haxe packages are folders and the files they contain are called **modules**. A module can itself contain one or more **types**.

To quote [the manual](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-modules-and-paths.html) :

> The (dot-)path to a type consists of the package, the module name and the type name. Its general form is pack1.pack2.packN.ModuleName.TypeName

There is two issues in your example :

- The module name must start with an uppercase, if you rename the module `test.hx` to `Test.hx`, you will be able to import the type with `import wow.Test.Test`. But since the module name and the type name are the same, you can omit the module name and just use `import wow.Test`.
- You need to declare the package in the module test : `package wow;`